# Find The Critical Numbers: h(p)= (p-4)/(p^2+2)

Tags: calculus

I have found the derivative of this rational polynomial but I am stuck at this point. The numerator cannot be factored. I set $h'(x)=0$. What should I do? Is the answer DNE? [image]

Comment: You should avoid posting questions in picture form. Please have a look at our [basic guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typesetting math here.

Comment: Just a curiosity, but... do red and blue have a special meaning here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Use the quadratic formula to find the solutions to the numerator. Those will be the critical numbers.

Answer (score 0):

yes your solution is right. Solve the quadratic equation to get two critical points which are

$x_0=8.24264...$ and $x_1=-0.2426..$